# Is this C++11 regex error me or the compiler?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11

OK, this isn't the original program I had this problem in, but I duplicated it in a much smaller one. Very simple problem.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex r1("S");
    printf("S works.\n");
    regex r2(".");
    printf(". works.\n");
    regex r3(".+");
    printf(".+ works.\n");
    regex r4("[0-9]");
    printf("[0-9] works.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled successfully with this command, no error messages:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
```

The last line of `g++ -v`, by the way, is:

```
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
```

And the result when I try to run it:

```
$ ./a.out 
S works.
. works.
.+ works.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted
```

It happens the same way if I change r4 to `\\s`, `\\w`, or `[a-z]`. Is this a problem with the compiler? I might be able to believe that C++11's regex engine has different ways of saying "whitespace" or "word character," but square brackets not working is a stretch. Is it something that's been fixed in 4.6.2?

**EDIT:**

Joachim Pileborg has supplied a partial solution, using an extra `regex_constants` parameter to enable a syntax that supports square brackets, but neither `basic`, `extended`, `awk`, nor `ECMAScript` seem to support backslash-escaped terms like `\\s`, `\\w`, or `\\t`.

**EDIT 2:**

Using raw strings (`R"(\w)"` instead of `"\\w"`) doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I haven't used the regex classses yet, but are you sure you're using the correct one? I recall C++11 having several different ways to interpret regex.

Comment: Is there any useful info in the `regex_error`?

Comment: @jswolf19 I don't know how to determine that; exception handling isn't one of my stronger skills.

Comment: @jswolf19 there certainly is. in OP's case, it contains `regex_constants::error_brack` ("mismatched brackets"), although it's not terribly helpful.

Comment: Do you know how to catch an exception? If you catch `regex_error` it will have a method called `code()` that will return a constant from `std::regex_constants::error_type`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/error_type for their meanings.

Comment: As of G++ 4.7.2, there's a problem with gcc. I have the same problem however VC++ 2012 works perfectly

Comment: The problem is still there with g++-4.8.1. No \w, no [a-z].

Comment: related question ["Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12530406/52074)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Update: `<regex>` is now implemented and released in GCC 4.9.0

---

<sup>Old answer:</sup>

ECMAScript syntax accepts `[0-9]`, `\s`, `\w`, etc, see [ECMA-262 (15.10)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Here's an example with `boost::regex` that also uses the ECMAScript syntax by default:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using namespace boost;
  regex e("[0-9]");
  return argc > 1 ? !regex_match(argv[1], e) : 2;
}
```

It works:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x *.cc -lboost_regex && ./a.out 1
```

According to the C++11 standard (28.8.2) `basic_regex()` uses `regex_constants::ECMAScript` flag by default so it must understand this syntax.

> Is this C++11 regex error me or the compiler?

[gcc-4.6.1 doesn't support c++11 regular expressions (28.13)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

Comment: Like I said in my edit, my current problem is backslashes, not square brackets. And I don't understand your last bit -- I've been using that compiler and some of these regexes have been working. Besides, I don't see any reference on that page to 4.6.1 in particular.

Comment: @Shay Guy: 1. ECMAScript syntax also supports backslashes and much more (the syntax is similar to the perl5 regex syntax if it is more familiar to you). 2. If gcc's current trunk (future) doesn't support regular expressions then it follows that gcc-4.6.1 (past) doesn't support it.

Comment: I still don't follow. If gcc doesn't support regex, then why did _any_ of these work without throwing an error? Even square brackets worked with some `regex_constants` parameters, despite backslashes not working right.

Comment: @Shay Guy: [the status page that I've linked above](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) says that there is *partial* support for some things. Go to the page, look for `28` (regular expressions section).

Comment: u can use clang for std::regex afaik, building it is somewhat straightforward: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/llvm-clang-libc-linux/

Comment: @smerlin: I saw it, but the question is about gcc. It is even simpler to install `boost::regex`: `apt-get install libboost-regex-dev`. The interface is almost the same only the namespace is different.

Comment: @ShayGuy - This is clearly the correct answer. It is unfortunate that g++'s libstdc++ doesn't yet support full regex's. One solution that leaves your code free to switch away from boost is your own namespace and a bunch of using directives to import the stuff you need from the boost or std namespace.

Answer (score 31):

The error is because creating a regex by default uses ECMAScript syntax for the expression, which doesn't support brackets. You should declare the expression with the `basic` or `extended` flag:

```
std::regex r4("[0-9]", std::regex_constants::basic);
```

**Edit** Seems like libstdc++ (part of GCC, and the library that handles all C++ stuff) doesn't fully implement regular expressions yet. In their [status document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) they say that *Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar* is not implemented yet.

Comment: That's sort of disappointing. Why did they make the default be something so strange? How annoying. Is there good documentation to be found anywhere on what the various syntaxes are?

Comment: @ShayGuy - This page contains a list of the possible syntaxes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type - I bet that `::std::regex_constants::extended` would work.

Comment: @Omnifarious See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type for the different expression types.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Found it. But it doesn't say what things are allowed or not allowed by the various syntaxes.

Comment: @Omnifarious There are links to the `basic`, `extended` and `awk` syntaxes. For the rest you just have to google it yourself it seems.

Comment: @Omnifarious Same story. Works with `[0-9]`, but not `\\w`. (Would there be a way to set the syntax once for the entire program, or at least the entire sourcefile?)

Comment: @ShayGuy - Just make your own function for creating them that supplies the extra argument. Make it `inline` in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @ShayGuy The error code in the exception for `\\w` is `error_escape` ("The expression contains an invalid escaped character or a trailing escape.") Seems to work for `\\\\w` though if it will be correct or not I don't now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `regex r5("\\\\w", regex_constants::awk)` doesn't throw an error, but `regex_match("foo",r5)` returns `false`. Curiously, the same happens with `\\foo`.

Comment: @ShayGuy After reading a little, it seems that regular expressions of `ECMAScript` should support things like `\w`. Unfortunately I don't have a C++11 compiler at work and can't test it.

Comment: -1: [ECMAScript supports `[0-9]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler/8061172#8061172).

Answer (score 7):

Regex support improved between gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9.2. For example, the regex `=[A-Z]{3}` was failing for me with:

> Regex error

After upgrading to gcc 4.9.2, it works as expected.

Comment: By "support improved between gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9.2" what you really mean to say is that "GCC 4.8 has no regex support; GCC 4.9 has regex support". [The availability of the experimental header in pre-4.9 versions is an unfortunate and misleading historical legacy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/560648).

Comment: Actually 4.8 has the std::regex class and friends, but the support for regex language was incomplete, hence your code would compile but not match as expected.

Comment: I am capable of reading a short comment to the end and even clicking on links. We seem to disagree on the definition of "support".

Comment: Not necessarily. GCC 4.8 simply did not support the regex implementation that was shipped, it being known not to be an actual C++11 regex implementation. It was not compliant and was never deemed as so. Such is the misfortune of it having been shipped in a header accessible as `<regex>`. This is my point.