# regex_search throwing std::regex_error

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11

```
std::cmatch res;
std::string str = "<h2>I'm a piece of text</h2>";
std::regex rx("<h(.)>([^<]+)");
std::regex_search(str.c_str(), res, rx);
std::cout << res[1] << ". " << res[2] << "\n";
```

This simple piece of code should work? right? 
Apparently it doesn't:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted
```

Compiler( gcc 4.7.0 ) bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets in the regex seem to be causing the problem.  See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler) for more details and possible workarounds.

Also (from the same thread), gcc version 4.6.1 had only partial support for `std::regex`, I don't know if it has been fixed in version 4.7.0 yet

Comment: It has not been fixed AFAICT: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011