# c++ 11 regex error

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, libstdc++

Just an example code from `C++ Primer 5th Edition: 17.3.3. Using the Regular Expression Library`

Main file `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "regexcase.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    using_regex();
    return 0;
}
```

Header file `regexcase.h`:

```
#ifndef REGEXCASE_H_
#define REGEXCASE_H_

#include <regex>
#include <string>

void using_regex();
std::string parseCode(std::regex_constants::error_type etype);

#endif /* REGEXCASE_H_ */
```

Source file `regexcase.cpp`:

```
#include "regexcase.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void using_regex() {
    // look for words that violate a well-known spelling rule of thumb, "i before e, except after c":
    // find the characters ei that follow a character other than c
    string pattern("[^c]ei");
    // we want the whole word in which our pattern appears
    pattern = "[a-zA-Z]*" + pattern + "[a-zA-Z]*";  //[a-zA-Z]*   [[:alpha:]]*
    try {
        regex r(pattern, regex_constants::extended);    // construct a regex to find pattern                // , regex_constants::extended
        smatch results;     // define an object to hold the results of a search
        // define a string that has text that does and doesn't match pattern
        string test_str = "receipt freind theif receive";
        // use r to find a match to pattern in test_str
        if (regex_search(test_str, results, r)) // if there is a match
            cout << results.str() << endl;      // print the matching word
        else
            cout << "no match for " << pattern << endl;
    } catch (regex_error &e) {
        cout << "what: " << e.what() << "; code: " << parseCode(e.code()) << endl;
    }
}

string parseCode(regex_constants::error_type etype) {
    switch (etype) {
    case regex_constants::error_collate:
        return "error_collate: invalid collating element request";
    case regex_constants::error_ctype:
        return "error_ctype: invalid character class";
    case regex_constants::error_escape:
        return "error_escape: invalid escape character or trailing escape";
    case regex_constants::error_backref:
        return "error_backref: invalid back reference";
    case regex_constants::error_brack:
        return "error_brack: mismatched bracket([ or ])";
    case regex_constants::error_paren:
        return "error_paren: mismatched parentheses(( or ))";
    case regex_constants::error_brace:
        return "error_brace: mismatched brace({ or })";
    case regex_constants::error_badbrace:
        return "error_badbrace: invalid range inside a { }";
    case regex_constants::error_range:
        return "erro_range: invalid character range(e.g., [z-a])";
    case regex_constants::error_space:
        return "error_space: insufficient memory to handle this regular expression";
    case regex_constants::error_badrepeat:
        return "error_badrepeat: a repetition character (*, ?, +, or {) was not preceded by a valid regular expression";
    case regex_constants::error_complexity:
        return "error_complexity: the requested match is too complex";
    case regex_constants::error_stack:
        return "error_stack: insufficient memory to evaluate a match";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

The output of calling `using_regex();` is `what: regex_error; code: error_brack: mismatched bracket([ or ])`

It seems that the regex can't **parse** the bracket.

Refer to Answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler), I use `regex_constants::extended` to initialize the regex object, which then is `regex r(pattern, regex_constants::extended);`

Then the output is `no match for [[:alpha:]]*[^c]ei[[:alpha:]]*`

It seems that the regex can't **match** the pattern.

Then I use `[a-zA-Z]*` to replace character class `[[:alpha:]]*` (with `regex_constants::extended` still set). The output still is `no match for [a-zA-Z]*[^c]ei[a-zA-Z]*`

Platform: `windows`

Tools used: `Eclipse for C/C++`; `MinGW (g++ --version: g++ 4.7.2)`

**EDIT**:
Thanks @sharth, add main file to complete the code.

Comment: Hard to debug a Regular Expression without knowing what input you're giving it.  Otherwise, stellar question.

Comment: It's hidden in there as `test_str`.

Comment: In gcc-4.7 `std::tr1::regex` is not complete/functional. Use `boost::regex` instead.

Comment: I have had run into similar problems while using <regex> . It turned out the full regex was not supported in my gcc (4.6) . Then I used boost::regex and things ran smoothly. (I was already using boost).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did a test using libc++ and clang++. This works as expected. Here's my main:

```
int main() {
    string test_str = "receipt freind theif receive";
    string pattern = "[a-zA-Z]*[^c]ei[a-zA-Z]*";

    try {
        regex r(pattern, regex_constants::extended);
        smatch results;

        if (regex_search(test_str, results, r))
            cout << results.str() << endl;
        else
            cout << "no match for " << pattern << endl;
    } catch (regex_error &e) {
        cout << "what: " << e.what() << "; code: " << parseCode(e.code()) << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
freind
```

---

On the other hand GCC 4.7.2, gives this result:

```
no match for [a-zA-Z]*[^c]ei[a-zA-Z]*
```

This is because in GCC 4.7.2's libstdc++, they still don't implement regex. Here's the implementation of `regex_search`:

```
template<typename _Bi_iter, typename _Allocator, typename _Ch_type, typename _Rx_traits>
inline bool regex_search(_Bi_iter __first, _Bi_iter __last, match_results<_Bi_iter, _Allocator>& __m, const basic_regex<_Ch_type, _Rx_traits>& __re, regex_constants::match_flag_type __flags) {
    return false;
}
```

---

And just to note, it is very helpful to include a small program that readers could compile. That way there is no confusion about what code is being run.

Comment: So what shall I do?
Use `boost::regex` instead, shall I?
(as @Maxim Yegorushkin said above)

Comment: Boost's implementation would work fine. In fact, I just did a quick test using Boost's 1.53.0 and GCC 4.7.2 and it worked the same as libc++.

Comment: What version of `clang`? The above doesn't work on 3.3 rc2.

Comment: @wvxvw: I was likely using whatever version of clang was included with OS X at the time. The larger issue, however, is that libstdc++ does not include support for `regex`. So, on OS X, you can do `-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11`. On Linux, you will likely need to use boost's implementation.