# Regex Extractor

Tags: c++, regex

Hi I am implementing regex using C++ .

Background:

I have a `std::string` and a `std::regex`. I need to compare the string against this regex .
The regex used here is not about validation . My typical regex would be something
like

`a[bc]{2}` and nothing beyond this scope

I have to pass this regex as a char pointer argument to a function .

Problem:
I am unable to assign char pointer to `std::regex`. If I do so I am getting the following error.

terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::regex_error  what():  regex_error`

My function body will be

```
std::string s((char*)a);  // The main string
std::regex e((char*)b); // Regex comparing the main string. a and b are the parameters to the function

if (std::regex_match(s, e))
{
    // returns the matched portion of the string 
    //  for instance  "abcdeef"  , "e{2}" would return ee
}
else 
{
      // return "Mismatch"
}
```

Any suggestions..? Or is there a way to extract the string from regex like `"a{2}b"` -> `"aab"`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably raised due to the `ECMAScript syntax for the expression` which doesn't support `[]` in regex. You can try with using the `basic` regex constrain tag.

```
std::regex e((char*)b, std::regex_constants::basic);
```

They are discussing more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler).

Comment: Thanks I have amended the code , I am getting the following error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: For your information a and b are const unsigned char*