# How to extract substring by using start and end delimiters in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a string from command line input, like this:

```
string input = cmd_line.get_arg("-i"); // Filepath for offline mode
```

This looks like a file as below:

```
input = "../../dataPosition180.csv"
```

I want to extract out the `180` and store as an `int`.

In python, I would just do:

```py
data = int(input.split('Position')[-1].split('.csv')[0])
```

How do I replicate this in C++?

Comment: [Find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) the first [digit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), then use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the number.

Comment: Or use a regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073839/c-extract-number-from-the-middle-of-a-string

Comment: What exactly does `180` represent here? I.e. in hypothetical example of path being `../45/123/4data25Position180_1.csv` what would be the number you are looking for?

Comment: @SergeyA that won't happen. It will only be as specified in the post.

Comment: Than just follow @Someprogrammerdude suggestion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you provide example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (somewhat verbose) solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string input = "../../dataPosition180.csv";
  // We add 8 because we want the position after "Position", which has length 8.
  int start = input.rfind("Position") + 8;
  int end = input.find(".csv");
  int length = end - start;
  int part = atoi(input.substr(start, length).c_str());
  cout << part << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int getDataPositionId (const string& input){
    regex mask ("dataPosition(\\d+).csv");
    smatch match;    
    if (! regex_search(input, match, mask)){
        throw runtime_error("invalid input");
    }
    return std::stoi(match[1].str());
}
```